# Unknown column 'items' in 'where clause' (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What is the problem؟

code:

```
  $this->db->select('items.*, tags.name, users.user_name');
  $this->db->from('items');
  $this->db->join('tags', 'tag = tags.id');
  $this->db->join('users', 'id_user = users.id');
  $this->db->where('items', array('id' => $id));
  $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
```

print :

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'items' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT `items`.*, `tags`.`name`, `users`.`user_name` 
FROM `items` JOIN `tags` ON `tag` = `tags`.`id` 
JOIN `users` ON `id_user` = `users`.`id` WHERE `items` = Array
```

> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
$this->db->where('items', array('id' => $id));
```

try this

```
$this->db->where('items.id', $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no column name `items` , the `items` is a table.